# Binding Visibility to Text.Length

Tags: wpf, xaml

I implemented a small visual indicator (just a textblock with a border), that should be hidden if there is no text to be shown at the moment. The text is bound to the `Indicator` property, the data context seems to be set correctly.

What I got so far is this (indicator text appears, hide/show doesn't work):

```
<Border>
    <Border.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Indicator.Length}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Border.Style>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Indicator}" />
</Border>
```

My problem is that the element is *not* hidden if the text length is zero.

Do you spot my mistake?

Indicator is part of the corresponding viewmodel:

```
public string Indicator
{ get; set;}
```

---

**UPDATE**

It works if I change the property above to this:

```
public const string IndicatorPropertyName = "Indicator";
private string _indicator = "";
public string Indicator
{
    get
    { return _indicator;}

    set
    {
        if (_indicator == value) { return;}

        RaisePropertyChanged(IndicatorPropertyName);
    }
}
```

**Why does it only work, if I raise PropertyChanged event?**

Comment: Do you raise the PropertyChanged-Event for Indicator? What appends if Indicator is set to null?

Comment: No, I don't raise PropertyChanged-Event. The indicator value is only set in the constructor once for testing purpose, so I thought updates to the property don't matter right now.

Comment: @Jehof: Ups, it works if I raise PropertyChanged for Indicator. But I don't understand why...?

Comment: Probably the `Length` property gets updated, either, as soon as you raise the `PropertyChanged` event on a `string` property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think as the name implies a Trigger only executes or checks its state when an event occurs. 
In case of a DataTrigger it is the `PropertyChanged`-Event of the interface `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Wihout raising the Event the DataTrigger doesn´t know that he has to check the binding and if the value meets the trigger condition.

Answer (score 2):

Your source binding is `Indicator` which is a plain CLR property.

WPF is based heavily on data binding. Bound objects update automatically when the binding source changes because under the hood a change notification is raised. When bounding to a dependency property (that is a property type understood only by WPF) you already have built in change notification for bound objects. No extra work is required.

You can also bound to plain CLR properties but in this case there is no built-in change notification for bound objects. You need to implement the change notification programmatically. This is done by raising the `PropertyChanged` event. The objects bound to that CLR property will be notified of value change and will update themselves.

In short if you want a CLR property to update a target binding, you need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise the PropertyChanged event.